# Is inheritance supported in views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I basically have a model that consists of another model that is a base class with 2 sub classes. How would I use this in my view. Obviously the main model would be passed into the view; however how would I cast the the submodel to one of it's subsclassesclasses? Please see the following for an example of what I mean. In my view I would have the TransporationModel. Say we are collecting data for this model from a form, and the current form is getting details for a Car type Vehicle. On submitting the form how would I cast the Car to its base type Vehicle?

```
public class TransaportationModel
{
    public VehicleModle vehicle { get; set; }
    ...other fields
}
```

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

```
Car car = new Car { /*Properties*/ };
Vehicle vehicle = (car as Vehicle);
```

From Wikipedia:
"The model manages the behavior and data of the application domain, responds to requests for information about its state (usually from the view), and responds to instructions to change state (usually from the controller). In event-driven systems, the model notifies observers (usually views) when the information changes so that they can react."

This means the individual classes that manage your data aren't 'models' perse. It is all of these classes together that create the model. You should look more into MVC pattern and thinking in objects.